# Delay before getting URLs into Google's in web index?

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, xml-sitemap

4 days ago, I have submitted a `sitemap.xml` into Google's WebMaster Tool for a new website. It contains 3 entries. I have tested the site map and Google found not errors.

In about how much time can I expect URL entries to be added in Google's web index? It is still 0 for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience:

with no sitemap submitted, it might take more than 30 days, with sitemap it usually takes a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no timetable for when Google will crawl and/or index your pages. For new sites it usually is a not very quick process unless you happen to get a high quality link or two pointing to your pages. That always speeds things along but rarely happens. The best thing you can do to speed up the process is to promote your site and seek realted/quality links to your pages.

Comment: Ok, is there an upper bound approximation (like 1 week, 1 month, more)?

Comment: 1-6 months. Speed depends on having relevent incoming links from other authoritative websites and relevent content for them to point at.

Answer (score 0):

As earlier people have said that there is no fixed time and if you contact Google, they also won't give you a fixed time period. Their reply will be that we update it regularly in few weeks.

But while the sitemap is not indexed, if you make any changes in the websites then make sure to resubmit your sitemap.